# Error in Angular 5 Project - "An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts"

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using the observable object in an Angular 5 project of mine - up until a week or so ago it was running fine, now all of a sudden I'm getting the following error:

ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(20,31): error TS1183: An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts.

I'm a bit of a newbie with Angular so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37448491/angular-2-typescript-an-implementation-cannot-be-declared-in-ambient-contexts

Comment: @RagavanRajan I don't think it's a duplicate of that, because the error get's thrown by rxJS and this file is a declaration file.

Comment: @chr15r please show us some context. How did you import `Observable` and how did you use it?

Comment: Same Error: ERROR in node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.d.ts(14,29): error TS1183: An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts.
The entire Observable.d.ts file is:
export * from 'rxjs-compat/Observer';    This gives this error in Visual Studio Code:  [ts] Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observer'.,,  This is a brand new project with a brand new NODE.js V8.11.2 just pulled down yesterday.  NPN - V -5.6.0

Answer (score 8):

In Angular 6 my Observables worked, but a "ng build --prod" gave the TS1183 error.
My solution was:

npm install rxjs

Answer (score 1):

I tried reinstalling "rxjs" with the following command:

```
npm install rxjs
```

This didn't solved my problem.

The only thing that worked for me it was:

> Replacing node_module folder with a new one

You can get it from new project or even delete and recreated it by executing:

```
npm install
```

*Note: I would suggest to take it from new created project, for some reason this command do not work sometimes.*

Answer (score 0):

npm install typescript@'>=2.7.0 <2.8.0

Comment: updating typeScript version causes a new error ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.1.1 and <3.3.0 but 3.3.3333 was found instead.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was my old angular-cli version :

- npm uninstall -g angular-cli
- npm cache clean / npm cache verify npm
- install -g @angular /cli@latest npm install

  and this one is to update your local project version:
- rm -rf node_modules
- npm uninstall --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
- npm install

You might also need to install rxjs-compat(to make your old code to work). The new RxJS 6 is a bit different.