# Compilation error in Angular

Tags: angular

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { GlobalConfig } from './toastr-config';

export declare class ToastrModule {
 error(arg0: any): any {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
 };
 success(arg0: any): any {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
 };
 setRootViewContainerRef(arg0: any): any {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
 };
 constructor(parentModule: ToastrModule);
 static forRoot(config?: Partial<GlobalConfig>): ModuleWithProviders;
}
```

Error

> ERROR in node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr/toastr.module.d.ts(5,27): error TS1183: An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts.
> node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr/toastr.module.d.ts(8,29): error TS1183: An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts.
> node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr/toastr.module.d.ts(11,45): error TS1183: An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts.
> src/app/user/signup/signup.component.ts(40,19): error TS2339: Property 'warning' does not exist on type 'ToastrModule'.
> src/app/user/signup/signup.component.ts(44,19): error TS2339: Property 'warning' does not exist on type 'ToastrModule'.
> src/app/user/signup/signup.component.ts(47,19): error TS2339: Property 'warning' does not exist on type 'ToastrModule'.
> src/app/user/signup/signup.component.ts(50,19): error TS2339: Property 'warning' does not exist on type 'ToastrModule'.
> src/app/user/signup/signup.component.ts(53,19): error TS2339: Property 'warning' does not exist on type 'ToastrModule'.
> src/app/user/signup/signup.component.ts(57,19): error TS2339: Property 'warning' does not exist on type 'ToastrModule'.

> i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular 2 typescript An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37448491/angular-2-typescript-an-implementation-cannot-be-declared-in-ambient-contexts)

Comment: What are you trying to do here?